# error writing in a file in json format.Stream closed

Tags: java, json, file, ioexception, writer

```
      HttpGet getRequest=new HttpGet("/rest/auth/1/session/");
          getRequest.setHeaders(headers);
          HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080, "http");
          HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("/rest/auth/1/session/");
          System.out.println("executing request to "+target +getRequest);
          HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(target,postRequest);
          HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
          if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
          }
```

the response from servers is in Json format is stored in httpresponse and we get the entity and put it in httpentity

```
 File fJsonFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Ashish\\Desktop\\filename.json");
              try {
                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                    if (!fJsonFile.exists()) {
                        fJsonFile.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fJsonFile.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                    bw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Output of EntityUtils.toString(entity) is in JSON format

```
{"self":"http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/user?username=vgupta","name":"vgupta","loginInfo":{"loginCount":55,"previousLoginTime":"2014-12-01T11:39:43.883+0530"}}
```

and following exception at line bw.write(EntityUtils.toString(entity));

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:74)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:244)
at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:288)
at jira.JiraGetPostDeleteReq.main(JiraGetPostDeleteReq.java:68)
```

how to get rid of this error.

If I want to write JSON in a file.

Comment: entity is http entity which receives json content

Comment: File fJsonFile = new 'File("C:\\Users\\Ashish\\Desktop\\filename.json");' should be within the try block. already tried that didn't work

Comment: Looking at the stack trace , it seems there is a zip functionality involved. Can you specify which line of the your code is stack trace pointing to?

Comment: Please show us every usage of `entity` relevant to this block of code.

Comment: You can edit your question with the appropriate details.

Comment: did it is their anything more you like me to add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be specified in the javadoc, but `EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)` closes the `HttpEntity`'s `InputStream`. Since you're invoking the method twice with the same `HttpEntity`, the second time it is already closed.

Instead of invoking it twice, store the result

```
String content = null;
if (entity != null) {
    content = System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
}
```

and reuse `content` everywhere else.

Comment: thanks a lot mate. I will probably like to upvote you but i dont have reputation of 15 yet.